# Input Text in input element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

So I want to enter something in an `<input>` element on a website, but I can't find any info on how to do it. I tried something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('id').input('Hello World')
```

But there is no command called `.input()`, but I hope this shows what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.value`

```
document.getElementById('id').value = 'Hello World';
```